# Selecting one repeated column in a dataframe on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following dataframe,

```
index c1 c1 c1 c2 c2 c2
0     1  2  0  1  1  2
1     2  1  1  0  0  2
2     0  0  1  2  2  1
```

it's obvious that `df['c1']` returns

```
index c1 c1 c1
0     1  2  0
1     2  1  1
2     0  0  1
```

Now, how do I select over those three columns? Slicing doesn't seem to get the job done...

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:],idx[0]]
```

does return the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `iloc`

```
df['c1'].iloc[:,[0]] #-> a dataframe
df['c1'].iloc[:,0] #-> a ndarray
```